ld: unknown options: -T
Recently, I've been trying to make a PS1 game using CMake and psn00bsdk. For some reason though, it fails:
ld: unknown options: -T
This is my CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

include(../n00b/libpsn00b/cmake/internal_setup.cmake)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ../n00b/libpsn00b/cmake/sdk.cmake)

project(
    ps1hello
    LANGUAGES    C
    VERSION      1.0.0
    DESCRIPTION  "hello ps1"
)

file(GLOB _sources src/*.c)
message(STATUS "Sources: ${_sources}")

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

psn00bsdk_add_executable(ps1hello GPREL ${_sources})

install(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/hellops1.exe TYPE BIN)

Also yes, i know that using include like that is bad practice, but i think it's fine for a hello world program like this.
I did cmake ., make (the usual steps for compiling a cmake project)

you have to set toolchain before project.

The -T option doesn't exist on macOS with the default Xcode build chain.   You will have to modify the Cmake configuration to avoid generating -T, or find the equivalent option and generate that instead, or install a tool chain that does understand the option and configure Cmake to use that.

i've already tried changing -T to --script, it gave me the same error:
unknown options: --script. Also, i did also try setting the toolchain before the project, still didn't change anything
